# Api typeahead search using RxJs switchMap sending too many requests (angular)

Tags: angular, rxjs, python-requests, subscribe, switchmap

I'm currently building a type ahead search. I'm trying to adapt it from the example here https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/recipes/type-ahead but I need to make an http call on keystroke. I'm testing it against timezones from my api. It works, but it seems to be compounding api calls every time I input a `keyup`.

If I type 'us' it will return results and make two identical api calls. If I add 'a' to make 'usa' it will then make 3 api calls. If I backspace a letter it makes 4, so on and so forth.

From my understanding `switchMap` is supposed to cancel calls that are going as newer ones come in, but it doesn't seem to do that with my implementation. I cannot for the life of me figure out why it's doing this when I keep going over the example. I tried to use `.share()` to attempt to consolidate streams but it didn't seem to help.

Search service:

```js
results: any;

search(table: string, page: any, elementId: string) {
    const searchInput = document.getElementById(elementId);
    const keyup$ = fromEvent(searchInput, 'keyup');
    let searchQuery;
    keyup$.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      map((e: any) => searchQuery = e.target.value),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(value => this.apiDataService.getSearchData(this.apiDataService.apiBase + `/search?table=${table}&query=${searchQuery}&page=${page}`))
    )
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.results = res.body.data;
    });
  }
```

apiData service:

```js
getSearchData(dataUrl: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<[]>(dataUrl, this.httpOptions);
}
```

html component:

```html
<input id="timezoneSearch" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="search.params" (keyup)="search.search('timezone', '1', 'timezoneSearch')" mdbInput type="text">


<div class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let option of search.results"
 (click)="accordion.selectOption(obj.currentObject, option.uuid, 'admin', 'ktimezone')">                              
  {{option.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: You're creating multiple subscribers everytime you keyup - that's not the right way to setup your subscriptions

Comment: I'm aware I'm creating multiple subscribers, I detailed that in my post. Can you clarify how to set them up properly?

Comment: because of `(keyup)="search.search(...)"` your `search` function is being called multiple times as you type. That means for each `keyup` event a separate `keyup$` stream is created. It is correct that `switchMap` ensures that you only have one inner observable at a time within *one* stream. But here you have multiple stream with multiple `switchMap` instances that have no connection with each other.

Comment: Intuitively I would suggest you to bind the `keyup$` stream to the lifecycle of your view component (similar to @Loops answer). Just keep one subscription for the time the component is displayed and unsubscribe inside `ngOnDestroy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just subscribe to the input events of the input element:

```html
<input #timezoneSearch placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="search.params" mdbInput type="text">
```

```ts
  @ViewChild('timezoneSearch') timezoneSearch: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.timezoneSearch.nativeElement, 'input').pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      map((e: InputEvent) => e.target.value),
      switchMap(value => this.apiDataService.getSearchData(this.apiDataService.apiBase + `/search?table=${'timezone'}&query=${value}&page=${1}`))
    ).subscribe(
      res => this.results = res.body.data
    );

  }
```

Furthermore, you don't need to put the results in a field, but instead directly use the Observable in the template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let option of results$ | async"
 ...
</div>
```

```ts
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.results$ = fromEvent(this.timezoneSearch.nativeElement, 'input').pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      map((e: InputEvent) => e.target.value),
      switchMap(value => this.apiDataService.getSearchData(this.apiDataService.apiBase + `/search?table=${'timezone'}&query=${value}&page=${1}`)),
      map(res => res.body.data)
    );
```

Comment: Excellent! this worked like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just subscribe once (probably in ngAfterViewInit() since you are accessing the dom):

```
 const searchInput = document.getElementById('timezoneSearch');
    const keyup$ = fromEvent(searchInput, 'keyup');
    keyup$.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(), // I do not think is actually necessary
      switchMap(value => this.apiDataService.getSearchData(this.apiDataService.apiBase + `/search?table=${'timezone'}&query=${value}&page=${1}`))
    )
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.results = res.body.data;
    });
```

Another possibility would be to add a `take(1)` in your pipe, which seems a little odd to me but would provide you with the ability to provide the parameters as you did via html.

Comment: That could work but he would need to unsubscribe unless the search field is displayed all the time. `distinctUntilChanged` could be necessary in some cases (eg. selecting with arrow keys). I have the feeling  `take(1)` couldn't fix the issue. It still would send multiple search requests with stale parameter (one per additionally created stream).